# Help understanding when to use an infinitive in this excercise

Tags: future-tense, infinitive-vs-gerund

I was taking an English test and I haven't know which sentence is wrong. could you help me out?

> a) The telephone is ringing. I will go to answer it.
> b) I feel like going dancing tonight. Would you like to join me?

I don't know if in letter "a" I should say: ...I will go answer it, rather than I will go to answer it; or

In letter "b": I feel like going to dance, rather than I feel like going dancing tonight.

Answer (score 7):

> A) The telephone is ringing. I'll go **and** answer it.

"And" is often omitted by native speakers, so your impression was right there.

> B) I feel like going dancing tonight.

Sounds nice and natural to me, since we refer to this activity as "dancing". I can see how you might be worried about having two "-ing" verbs adjacent, but it's honestly a perfect construction. Your version: "I feel like going to dance", is also perfectly valid, but I just feel that "going dancing" sounds more natural.

**EDIT: (See @Tristan's comment)**

The British are unlikely to omit "and", as in "and answer the phone". The Americans are more likely to omit it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention which native speakers often omit the word **and**. Americans often do that but, British usually don't.

Comment: In fact, to my American ears, using the *and* makes me put the "*go and*" together in the same way that kids often use "go and" as extra filler: "Why don't you *go and* shutup."  "So he *goes and* tips over the basket" "So he *goes and* tells the teacher I did it."  "Why don't you *go and* shove it up your..." Ok, maybe I should stop.

Comment: Jim, that's just one of the differences between English use in the UK and the USA, where it is common for people to omit the word **and**. From my, English and British perspective, it is very strange to hear a word randomly omitted where it would be expected and normally included, in this part of the world.

Answer (score 2):

From a British English perspective.

Sentence a) is incorrect. Sentence b) is perfectly grammatical.
In response to a declarative sentence that the telephone is ringing I would reply:

> **I'll answer it.**

To actually say, "I will go and answer it" is overly formal. The subject and the auxiliary is nearly always contracted in speech. Furthermore,  to point out you will  go **and** do an action is unnecessary but this type of construction is common in speech.

> A: We don't have any more milk.
>    B: I will go out and purchase some milk ---> ***I'll*** (go and) **get some**.

Comment: You mentioned one of them being overly formal but, your  example *I will go out and purchase some milk*, is also formal. It would be more natural and common to say *I will go out and buy some milk*.

Comment: @Tristan That was my point, I'd transformed this formal sentence to the more informal and relaxed way: **I'll get some.**

Comment: Using *get* is another, natural and common way to say it.